# Centre Google Map marker on embeded map

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Cannot get this to work for the life of me, and I can't figure out why.

Ok...

On a wordpress post i have a custom field 'Post Code'. The script I have picks up the value of this field, runs it past google to get Lat and Long values and embeds the map. This is what I have:

```
$postcode = urlencode( get_field("tutor_post_code")); // post code to look up in this case status however can easily be retrieved from a database or a form post
    $request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$postcode."&sensor=true"; // the request URL you'll send to google to get back your XML feed
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");// XML request
    $status = $xml->status;// GET the request status as google's api can return several responses
    if ($status=="OK") {
        //request returned completed time to get lat / lang for storage
        $lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
        $long = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
        echo "$lat,$long";  //spit out results or you can store them in a DB if you wish
    }
    if ($status=="ZERO_RESULTS") {
        //indicates that the geocode was successful but returned no results. This may occur if the geocode was passed a non-existent address or a latlng in a remote location.
    }
    if ($status=="OVER_QUERY_LIMIT") {
        //indicates that you are over your quota of geocode requests against the google api
    }
    if ($status=="REQUEST_DENIED") {
        //indicates that your request was denied, generally because of lack of a sensor parameter.
    }
    if ($status=="INVALID_REQUEST") {
        //generally indicates that the query (address or latlng) is missing.
    }


    echo '<iframe width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=';
    echo get_field("tutor_post_code");
    echo '&zoom=13&center=';
    echo "$lat,$long";
    echo '&key=AIzaSyB8LLFEJV_Or1sj_u1PGKw12n6leDKND3o"></iframe>';
```

Any ideas why it's not centering the marker on the map?

Miro

Comment: did you try using urlencode when you use the post code to generate the url for your iframe?  You do this up top, so it's already in a variable, then at the bottom you just echo out the value, I'm not sure what you have in there so it could be problematic.  What does your generated iframe code look like?  Post the output

Comment: remove the center-parameter. Basically the geocoding is redundant, all you need is the q-parameter(the map will be centered automatically when the address/place has been found)

Comment: Hi, the centre parameter is there to centre the map, according to google. It also only works with lat and long values, hence i am geocoding the postcode above to get it. It is definitely returning the right coordinates. The map pointer always end up being in the top left corner of the iframe... [link](http://screencast.com/t/2sMhATBwr)

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it seems to be working fine.

One possibility is `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=`is returning a different result than your iframe Google Maps. (This does happen sometime.)

Like @Dr.Molle said, you don't really need to do center as it is default to center to the `q` point, unless you wants a different center.

Comment: Hi, as mentioned, the centre parameter is needed to centre the map, according to google, and it only takes lat & long coordinates, hence i am geocoding the postcode to get them. still not working. removing the centre parameter does not work.

Comment: What is the input you're trying..?

Comment: The input is the post code. it then returns the lat and long coordinates.